# "Subquery returned more than 1 value." error in SQL Manager

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
UPDATE Contact_UDF 
SET hasAttendedEvent = (
    SELECT CASE WHEN c.Contact_ID IN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT Contact_ID 
        FROM Action a 
        WHERE a.Action_Type_ID =39) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM Contact c)
```

I'm running this small bit of SQL to set a flag in the Contact_UDF table but keep running into the following error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

I can't for the life of me understand why, as I'm using IN not any of the operators it describes. Can anyone help?

Comment: The error says **or when the subquery is used as an expression**

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `SQLServer`?

Comment: You have two sub-queries. One of them follows "=" and the other follows IN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see why this gives this error, simply execute the subquery and conclude that it indeed returns more than one row:

```
SELECT CASE
              WHEN c.Contact_ID IN
                     (SELECT DISTINCT Contact_ID
                      FROM Action a
                      WHERE a.Action_Type_ID =39) THEN 1
              ELSE 0
          END
   FROM Contact c
```

It returns 1 row for each record in Contact.

You forgot a clause to make a 1 to 1 mapping between Contact_UDF and Contact:

```
UPDATE Contact_UDF udf
SET hasAttendedEvent =
  (SELECT CASE
              WHEN c.Contact_ID IN
                     (SELECT DISTINCT Contact_ID
                      FROM Action a
                      WHERE a.Action_Type_ID =39) THEN 1
              ELSE 0
          END
   FROM Contact c
   WHERE c.Contact_ID = udf.Contact_ID)
```

Of course, this assumes that 'c.Contact_ID = udf.Contact_ID' restricts the subquery to one row. I can't be sure that this is true without more information about your schema.

Answer (score 0):

Popovitsj and Laurence have it fairly well covered:

Your sub query can return multiple rows which don't behave like a list of values than you can use in 'in expression. However, you can use the exists function instead so :

```
UPDATE Contact_UDF udf
SET hasAttendedEvent =
  (SELECT CASE
              WHEN exists (
                     (SELECT a.Contact_ID
                      FROM Action a
                      WHERE a.Action_Type_ID =39
                      and a.Contact_ID = c.Contact_ID) 
                      THEN 1
              ELSE 0
          END
   FROM Contact c
   WHERE c.Contact_ID = udf.Contact_ID)
```

Documentation on exists function:
(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189259(v=sql.105).aspx)

Documenation on referencing column from main query in subquery:
(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Contact_UDF SET hasAttendedEvent = (SELECT
CASE WHEN c.Contact_ID IN (SELECT TOP 1 Contact_ID FROM Action a WHERE a.Action_Type_ID =39)    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM Contact c)
```

It looks like your sub-query could be returning more than 1 row. You need to ensure it only returns 1 for the case statement to work. The above modification will ensure it only returns 1.

Comment: I don't think just selecting a random row is a very smart thing to do. Two possibilities here, either the query is wrong according to the database-model, or there is some faulty data in the database. Just selecting top 1 doesn't fix either. Trying with `distinct` is much better, if its just duplicates it doesn't matter. But if distinct fails as well, one has to look at the data!